# Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\dist\php\login.php on line 2

Tags: php

Me salta este este error:

> Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\dist\php\login.php on line 2

Este es el código que tengo:

```php
<?php 
    session_start();
    
        include("con_db.php");

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            //something was posted
            $user_name = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
    
            if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($user_name))
            {
    
                //read from database
                $query = "SELECT * from datos where email = '$user_name' limit 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($conex, $query);
    
                if($result)
                {
                    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {
    
                        $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                        
                        if($user_data['password'] === $password)
                        {
    
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $user_data['email'];
                            header("Location: dashboard.php");
                            die;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                echo "wrong username or password!";
            }else
            {
                echo "wrong username or password!";
            }
        }
    
    ?>
```

Me gustaría saber como solucionarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Observa con atención porque podría ser que tienes una línea en blanco antes de `<?php` o después de cerrar `?>`.

Por ejemplo:

```
 <?php
// Nota el espacio que hay en "<?php"
?>
```

O bien

```
   echo "your code here";

?>
AQUÍ NO DEBEN HABER ESPACIOS EN BLANCO
```

Una opción es que podrías omitir la etiqueta de cierre `?>`; otra opción en caso de que este sea un archivo conjunto con HTML, es poner el `session_start();` antes de declarar el `DOCTYPE`.